# Is it possible to have a pdf slideshow inside a <div> or <embedded>?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a pdf with multiple pages that I want to display and change page automatically inside my main page 'index' I don't want a full screen option. My main goal is to create a dashboard with several information in a single webpage and screen.
This link: https://codepen.io/gabrieleromanato/pen/dImly has a slide with an example, but it has pictures.

One way I've been reading is to convert al the pages in to images and then do the slideshow using JavaScript

```
<div class="slider" id="main-slider"><!-- outermost container element -->
    <div class="slider-wrapper"><!-- innermost wrapper element -->
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/400/animals" alt="First" class="slide" /><!-- slides -->
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/400/business" alt="Second" class="slide" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/400/city" alt="Third" class="slide" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!